# element is not defined using for each loop in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

I want to get all the values in `element` by using `foreach` loop via jquery. but I am getting error as

> element is not defined

here is the code

```
if (data.length > 0) {           
        $.each(data, function (index, element) {
            Items += element[0] + ",";
            element;
        });
        Items = Items.substr(0, Items.length - 1);
        var Values = { "Items": Items, "Element": element };
        NEIQC_Service.ConfirmApprovalML(Values).then(function () {
        });
    }
```

Please suggest what is wrong.

**update**

after `console.log(element)`

I get data in element like below

`(5)["Delton Infra P Limited - 396475", "3310744", "SMALL CELL INDOOR WITHOUT DGS / SMALL CELL INDOOR WITHOUT DGS", "1", "0"]`

Comment: Your loop parameters is the problem. First one should be value. Second one should be the index

Comment: oops. loop is correct. but your element value should be assigned it to a public variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `element` gets out-of-scope outside the `each()` method, so `element` is indeed not defined at `var Values = { "Items": Items, "Element": element };`. To get away from this you may assign `element` to another variable whose scope is available from outside the `each()` method:

```
if (data.length > 0) {   
    let element2 ;        
    $.each(data, function (index, element) {
        Items += element + ",";
        element2 = element;
    });
    Items = Items.substr(0, Items.length - 1);
    var Values = { "Items": Items, "Element": element2 };
    NEIQC_Service.ConfirmApprovalML(Values).then(function () {
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because in [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) callback function first parameter is value and second is `index` and also

you need to change `Items += element[0] + ",";` to `Items += element + ",";` as `element` is not an array it will be string.

Try to change code like this:

```
$.each(data, function (element, index) {
  Items += element + ",";
  element;
});
```

Comment: not working, getting error as `Items = "undefined"`

Comment: Can you post `data` also

Answer (score 0):

```
data.map(element=>{
  Items += element[0] + ",";
  console.log(element) // Check it has value or not
  element;
}  
)
```

Comment: I have tested it , working fine . can you point the line witch throws error ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```js
var elem;
         
$.each([ 52, 97 ], function (index, element) {
    elem = element;
});

console.log(elem);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

with is now you can access `element` variable outside the callback function